# Accessing "Save Vector Layer As" algorithm in QGIS Processing Model?

Tags: qgis, layers, vector, model, save

I'm building a Processing Model in QGIS that ultimately exports a points shapefile (vector layer) as a CSV in a different coordinate system than the shapefile.

I ordinarily accomplish this in the "Save Vector Layer As" window (see image below) which I access by right-clicking on the shapefile in the Layers Panel. In this window, I uncheck field_1 and field_2 for export (I do not need those fields), and I export GEOMETRY "AS_YX" (I do need coordinates in the desired coordinate system to be written to the CSV).

[image: "Save Vector Layer As" window]

Can I access this "Save Vector Layer As" algorithm for use in a QGIS Processing Model?

Comment: I think it is not available in the model algorithmen. You can try to make a proccessing script instead. This should not be that much code.There is on class called: QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vlayer, "xy.csv", "utf-8", None, "CSV", layerOptions ='GEOMETRY=AS_WKT') which is doing the whole stuff.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question under our focussed Q&A format.  Please ask your "PS" as a separate question.

Answer (score 6):

You simply set any process' output as final output by naming the field below `<output vector>`, then there will be a dialogue where you want to save it to. Though you can not choose a desired CRS for example, that you'll have to set via transform before.

Comment: The PS should be asked as a separate question.